# How is the WordPress nonce generated?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to reproduce the wordpress "nonce" parameter. How is it generated? How is it related to the cookies?

From [codex.wordpress.com](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces):

> Nonces are generated using a key and salt that are unique to your site
>   if you have installed WordPress correctly. NONCE_KEY and NONCE_SALT
>   are defined in your wp-config.php file, and the file contains comments
>   that provide more information.

And so this I get out (`default-constants.php`):

```
function wp_cookie_constants() {
    /**
     * Used to guarantee unique hash cookies
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    if ( !defined( 'COOKIEHASH' ) ) {
        $siteurl = get_site_option( 'siteurl' );
        if ( $siteurl )
            define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( $siteurl ) );
        else
            define( 'COOKIEHASH', '' );
    }

    /**
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
    if ( !defined('USER_COOKIE') )
        define('USER_COOKIE', 'wordpressuser_' . COOKIEHASH);

    /**
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
    if ( !defined('PASS_COOKIE') )
        define('PASS_COOKIE', 'wordpresspass_' . COOKIEHASH);

    /**
     * @since 2.5.0
     */
    if ( !defined('AUTH_COOKIE') )
        define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_' . COOKIEHASH);

    /**
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    if ( !defined('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE') )
        define('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_sec_' . COOKIEHASH);

    /**
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    if ( !defined('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE') )
        define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'wordpress_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH);

    /**
     * @since 2.3.0
     */
    if ( !defined('TEST_COOKIE') )
        define('TEST_COOKIE', 'wordpress_test_cookie');

    /**
     * @since 1.2.0
     */
    if ( !defined('COOKIEPATH') )
        define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );

    /**
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    if ( !defined('SITECOOKIEPATH') )
        define('SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('siteurl') . '/' ) );

    /**
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    if ( !defined('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH') )
        define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );

    /**
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    if ( !defined('PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH') )
        define( 'PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', WP_PLUGIN_URL)  );

    /**
     * @since 2.0.0
     */
    if ( !defined('COOKIE_DOMAIN') )
        define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly your question is. What makes you think `NONCE_KEY/SALT` have anything to do with cookies?

Comment: See the [wp_salt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_salt/) function. And look at who calls it. The function (not that specific salt as their are so many) is used to authenticate session cookies.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is - what is it that you want to know? How the nonce parameter is generated?

Comment: yes i want to know how the nonce (ajax) parameter is created :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out, look at the WP source code.

Nonces are generated by the [`wp_create_nonce`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/) function in [`pluggable.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/pluggable.php). The real deal is this:

```
substr( wp_hash( $i . '|' . $action . '|' . $uid . '|' . $token, 'nonce' ), -12, 10 )
```

Where:

- `$i` is a form of timestamp (it increases by one at a fixed time interval, and a nonce has a lifetime of two such intervals).
- `$action` specifies what action the nonce is for (defaults to -1).
- `$uid` is the user ID (special rules apply if the user is logged out).
- `$token` is the session ID for the current session.

Taking a closer look at the [`wp_hash`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash/) function (located in the same file), we find this:

```
function wp_hash( $data, $scheme = 'auth' ) {
    $salt = wp_salt( $scheme );
    return hash_hmac( 'md5', $data, $salt );
}
```

So it's a MD5 HMAC. The [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function is a PHP core function. The variable that for some reason is called `$salt` is the HMAC key.

So what is the `$salt`? Clearly it's dependent on `$scheme` that is `"nonce"` in our case. For more info, take a look at the [`wp_salt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_salt/) function. In the comments, you'll find this:

> Salts are created using secret keys. Secret keys are located in two places: in the database and in the `wp-config.php` file. The secret key in the database is randomly generated and will be appended to the secret keys in `wp-config.php`.

For more details on exactly where it reads the keys, see the actual code. As far as I can tell, it's completely unrelated to any cookies.

**TL;DR:** The nonce is a MD5 HMAC of a timestamp, the action, the user id and the session id, keyed with a secrets stored in `wp-config.php` and the database.